# opencv2 error while setup ros environment

Tags: opencv2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While I was setting up the ROS environment in osx lion, I've got this error and I don't know what to do.

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 65040--65042
[]\T1/ptm/m/n/10 Slabaugh, G.G. Com-put-ing Eu-ler an-gles from a ro-ta-tion ma
-trix.
[794] [795] [796]
Underfull \hbox (badness 7740) in paragraph at lines 65291--65293
[]\T1/ptm/m/n/10 Jukka Iivari-nen, Markus Peura, Jaakko Srel, and Ari Visa. \T1
/ptm/m/it/10 Com-par-i-son of Com-bined

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 65291--65293
\T1/ptm/m/it/10 Shape De-scrip-tors for Ir-reg-u-lar Ob-jects\T1/ptm/m/n/10 , 8
th British Ma-chine Vi-sion Con-fer-ence, BMVC`97.
No file opencv2refman.ind.
[797] (./opencv2refman.aux)
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 bbm10
mktexpk: No such file or directory
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
 )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
!pdfTeX error: /usr/texbin/pdflatex (file bbm10): Font bbm10 at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
make[2]: *** [doc/CMakeFiles/docs] Error 70
make[1]: *** [doc/CMakeFiles/docs.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 56%] Building CXX object modules/contrib/CMakeFiles/opencv_contrib.dir/src/spinimages.cpp.o
[ 56%] Building CXX object modules/contrib/CMakeFiles/opencv_contrib.dir/src/stereovar.cpp.o
Linking CXX shared library ../../devel/lib/libopencv_contrib.dylib
[ 56%] Built target opencv_contrib
make: *** [all] Error 2

<== Failed to process package 'opencv2': 
  Command '/Users/ldsrogan/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/mk/catkin_generated/env_cached.sh make -j2' returned non-zero exit status 2
Command failed, exiting.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52211/opencv2-error-while-setup-ros-environment/) by [ldsrogan](https://answers.ros.org/users/3964/ldsrogan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-01-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like your tex installation has some issues. The error you have to solve is that:

Font bbm10 at 600 not found ==> Fatal error occurred

The thing is, that Opencv2 compiles its entire documentation during a make command. If you find a way to turn that off, please comment. If you just want to make it compile, reinstall your texlive environment

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3